# Bot postMessage missing icon and name

Tags: slack

Using a custom bot, I can `postMessage`s ([doc](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage)) into a channel (with the bot's auth-token). However, the messages don't show my bot's icon or name, just the default bot's one:

[image: slack-bot]

When I change topic, it works fine (i.e. the icon and name of my custom bot appear).

Is there some extra configuration needed?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Seems the `as_user=true` param is needed. [Doc](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage) is somewhat confusing in this regard:

```
as_user Optional
Pass true to post the message as the authed user, instead of as a bot
```

The authed user in this case, is the bot whose auth-token you've used.